# Documents with mandatory field filled in still left checked out

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, metadata

H, using Sharepoint 2013. I have a library with a column that is required to have data. It does not have a default. When I upload one document, the document panel pops up. I fill in the metadata field, including the required. I ht "Save" but the document remains checked out. How can I get SP to check in the file when I do fill in everything needed. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just check-in the document?  The act of checking in the document means that you have finished editing it.  If you don't check it in, it is still available for you to come back an hour later or a day or week later to edit it again, finalise your edits, then when you are ready, you check the document in.

Regarding the mandatory fields - these field need to be filled in before the document can be checked in.  Filling in mandatory fields is not the same thing as checking in a document.

Just do a search on check-in check-out and you'll find plenty of info about it's purpose.

Comment: Hi, I know how check in and checkout work. The problen is the upload form has  a button on the bottom that is "Save". This "saves" the information, but does not check in the document. To have a panel that pops up, asks for information , closes and you still have to go and find the document and preform a "checkin" from the rinbbon is very bad UX. Why can't the upload form check to see if the required field is filled in and then checkin ?